Why does Angular 18 breaks "inline" imported modules?
In previous Angular versions (< v18) it was possible to import modules dynamically based on a variable inside of a method, like
initTemplates(moduleName: string): Observable<ScoreboardModule> {

    // NOT WORKING ANYMORE
    let promise = import(`./layouts/${moduleName}/${moduleName}.module`);

    // THIS WORKS
    // let promise = import(`./layouts/BER/BER.module`);

    return from(promise).pipe(
        map(mod => mod.ScoreboardModule),
        map((module: any) => {
            // do some stuff

            return module;
        })
    );
}

The ng serve output shows
▲ [WARNING] The glob pattern import("./layouts/**/*/**/*.module") did not match any files [empty-glob]

    src/app/mode.competition/components/scoreboard-viewer/scoreboardViewer.abstract.ts:30:29:
      30 │ ...t promise = import(`./layouts/${moduleName}/${moduleName}.module`)
         ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

When accessing the code the application breaks with:
 Error: Module not found in bundle: ./layouts/BER/BER.module
    at chunk-SKK7EFDP.js:26:9

the additional paths are defined in tsconfig.app.json like this:
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
        "types": ["node"]
    },
    "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/app/mode.competition/components/scoreboard-viewer/layouts/**/*.ts"]
}

This code was running as described above at least since Angular 13 and breaks suddenly now in Angular 18.
The described issue is part of a real huge software package that cannot be extracted easily. I really hope that the error description is enough to identify the error, without a code example here.
Please does anybody has any ideas, on how to fix it?
